# The Closure Of Regular Language Under Reordering Alphabets

Tags: regular-languages

For a regular language $A$ with the alphabet $\{a, b\}$. Is $L$ a regular language, where $L$ contains strings of $A$ but sorted with $a$ and $b$?

In other words, formula: $L = \{ a^{\#_a(x)}b^{\#_b(x)} \mid x\in A\}$, where $\#_a(x)$ is the number of $a$'s and $\#_b(x)$ is the number of $b$'s.

$A$ is a regular language. Is $L$ a regular language?

I found some examples and counterexamples:

When $A = a*$, $L=a*$ is regular.

When $A = (ab)^*$, $L=\{a^n b^n \mid n \ge 0\}$ is not regular.

However, I still couldn't convince myself that in a general case when the star operator $(...)^*$ in $A$ contains both $a$ and $b$, $L$ is not regular.

Any idea about this question?

Answer (score 1):

When $A$ is equal to the starred regular $\{a,b\}^*$ then $L$ equals $a^* b^*$, which is again regular. So in general the existence of both $a$'s and $b$'s does not imply nonregularity.

(Thank you nir shahar for the correction.)

Comment: When $A=\{a,b\}^*$ then $L=L(a^*b^*)\neq \{a,b\}^*$. Nevertheless, its still a regular language.

Comment: @nirshahar Thank you!